# Listjs Multiple Filtering and Sorting

Tags: sorting, filter, listjs

I am trying to make it so I can filter by multiple items including what is currently Searched or sorted.  Currently it works if I filter with a single item and if it is sorted or searched, but it does not work with two or more filters.  I use check boxes so users can select what they want to filter by.  When I check a second filter, the previous filter is removed.  I checked the ListJS site but they only give the functions/API but there are no examples on how to use them.  I tried using one of the answers on another question on stackoverflow but it returned a blank query when I used a filter.  I would like to be able to search for example:  Male champions, Free to Play, and Tank or something similar.

Here is the page that I am trying to fix:  http://lolskin.comoj.com/champions.html

**Here is the javascript:**

```
    var options = {
valueNames: [ 'name', 'rp', 'ip', 'number', 'gender', 'sale', 'free', 'assassin', 'fighter', 'mage', 'marksman', 'support', 'tank' ]
};

var championList = new List('champions', options);

$('#genderx').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        championList.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.values().gender == 'm'){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }); //Only items with gender == m are shown in list
    }
    else{
        championList.filter();
    }
});//End Male Gender

$('#gendery').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        championList.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.values().gender == 'f'){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }); //Only items with gender == f are shown in list
    }
    else{
        championList.filter();
    }
});//End Female Gender

$('#salex').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        championList.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.values().sale == '1'){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }); //Only items with sale == 1 are shown in list
    }
    else{
        championList.filter();
    }
});//End Sale

$('#freex').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        championList.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.values().free == '1'){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }); //Only items with free == 1 are shown in list
    }
    else{
        championList.filter();
    }
});//End Free

$('#assassinx').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        championList.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.values().assassin == '1'){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }); //Only items with assassin == 1 are shown in list
    }
    else{
        championList.filter();
    }
});//End Assassin

$('#fighterx').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        championList.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.values().fighter == '1'){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }); //Only items with fighter == 1 are shown in list
    }
    else{
        championList.filter();
    }
});//End Fighter

$('#magex').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        championList.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.values().mage == '1'){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }); //Only items with mage == 1 are shown in list
    }
    else{
        championList.filter();
    }
});//End Mage

$('#marksmanx').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        championList.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.values().marksman == '1'){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }); //Only items with marksman == 1 are shown in list
    }
    else{
        championList.filter();
    }
});//End Marksman

$('#supportx').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        championList.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.values().support == '1'){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }); //Only items with support == 1 are shown in list
    }
    else{
        championList.filter();
    }
});//End Support

$('#tankx').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        championList.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.values().tank == '1'){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }); //Only items with tank == 1 are shown in list
    }
    else{
        championList.filter();
    }
});//End Tank
```

Here is the HTML(I put it on DropBox since it is big):

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7665984/champions.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having change event assigned to each checkboxes,Use a form and a button to submit form with these checkboxes.Then do filter as

```
$('submitbutton').click(function() {
    championList.filter(function(item){
    // filtering logic here 
    });
}
```